# Zip File percentage UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, zip, percentage

I would like to see the percentage of each file zipping, I have tried incorrectly to solve this, here the code:

**MainPaga.xaml**:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5">
            <Button x:Name="BtnChooseFolder" Click="BtnChooseFolder_Click" Content="Choose Folder" Margin="5"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Folder to Zip: " VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="TxbFolderToZip" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5">
            <Button x:Name="BtnChooseDestination" Click="BtnChooseDestination_Click" Content="Choose Destination" Margin="5"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Zip Folder: " VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="TxbZipFolder" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button x:Name="BtnZip" Click="BtnZip_Click" Content="Zippa" Margin="10"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="TxbPercentage" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**:

```
string DestinationFolderPath = string.Empty;
string SourceFolderPath = string.Empty;

StorageFolder SourceFolder;
StorageFolder DestinationFolder;

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
}

private async void BtnChooseFolder_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FolderPicker FolderPickFol = new FolderPicker();
    FolderPickFol.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop;
    FolderPickFol.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
    Windows.Storage.StorageFolder SelectFolderToZipa = await FolderPickFol.PickSingleFolderAsync();
    StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.AddOrReplace("PickedFolder", SelectFolderToZipa);
    SourceFolder = SelectFolderToZipa;
    SourceFolderPath = SelectFolderToZipa.Path;
    TxbFolderToZip.Text = SourceFolderPath;
}

private async void BtnChooseDestination_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FolderPicker FolderPickFol = new FolderPicker();
    FolderPickFol.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop;
    FolderPickFol.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
    StorageFolder SelectFolderToZipa = await FolderPickFol.PickSingleFolderAsync();
    StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.AddOrReplace("PickedDestination", SelectFolderToZipa);
    DestinationFolder = SelectFolderToZipa;
    DestinationFolderPath = SelectFolderToZipa.Path;
    TxbZipFolder.Text = DestinationFolderPath;
}

private async void BtnZip_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    if (SourceFolder != null)
    {
        try
        {
            string appFolderPath = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path;
            StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.AddOrReplace("PickedFolderToken", SourceFolder);

            //Gets the folder named TestFolder from Documents Library Folder  
            StorageFolder sourceFolder = SourceFolder;

            //Creates a zip file named TestFolder.zip in Local Folder  
            StorageFile zipFile = await DestinationFolder.CreateFileAsync("TestFolder.zip", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            Stream zipToCreate = await zipFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();
            ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(zipToCreate, ZipArchiveMode.Create);

            await ZipFolderContentsHelper(sourceFolder, archive, sourceFolder.Path);
            archive.Dispose();
            MessageDialog msg = new MessageDialog("Success");
            await msg.ShowAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}


private async Task ZipFolderContentsHelper(StorageFolder sourceFolder, ZipArchive archive, string sourceFolderPath)
{
    IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> files = await sourceFolder.GetFilesAsync();

    foreach (StorageFile file in files)
    {
        var path = file.Path.Remove(0, sourceFolderPath.Length);
        ZipArchiveEntry readmeEntry = archive.CreateEntry(file.Path.Remove(0, sourceFolderPath.Length));
        ulong fileSize = (await file.GetBasicPropertiesAsync()).Size;
        byte[] buffer = fileSize > 0 ? (await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file)).ToArray() : new byte[0];

        using (Stream entryStream = readmeEntry.Open())
        {
            await entryStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            await Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
                {
                    double progress = entryStream.Position / buffer.Length;
                    TxbPercentage.Text = ((progress) * 100).ToString("0.00");
                });
            });
        }
    }

    IReadOnlyList<StorageFolder> subFolders = await sourceFolder.GetFoldersAsync();

    if (subFolders.Count() == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    foreach (StorageFolder subfolder in subFolders)
    {
         await ZipFolderContentsHelper(subfolder, archive, sourceFolderPath);
    }
}
```

> In the Stream in the ZipFolderContentsHelper method I opted for "entryStream.Position" but, this does not return the actual completed zipped size of the file... How can I proceed?

Always thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The `ZipArchiveFileEntry` class provides the Properties `Lenght` and `CompressedLength`. You can use those proerties to calculate the compression ratio. If you'll go with your approach, you hae to cast one of the length to a `double` before assigning it (`double progress = (double) entryStream.Position / buffer.Length`). But i'm not sure if that will yield to the correct result.

Comment: I found perhaps an example, but I can not adapt it because in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42430559/progress-bar-not-available-for-zipfile-how-to-give-feedback-when-program-seems) for the zip file we use the path in string and not the storage file but, it could be useful for the solution

Comment: Could you give an example of your answer?

Answer (score 0):

> In the Stream in the ZipFolderContentsHelper method I opted for "entryStream.Position" but, this does not return the actual completed size of the file... How can I proceed?

If your final requirement is to get the size of the zipped file. You could get it by using the [StorageFile.Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile.properties#Windows_Storage_StorageFile_Properties).

Then, you could call the [StorageFile.GetBasicPropertiesAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh701737) method. This method returns a BasicProperties object, which defines properties for the size of the item (file or folder) as well as when the item was last modified.

More information, please read [Getting a file's basic properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-getting-file-properties#getting-a-files-basic-properties) for details.

***[Updated on 2018/9/25]***

> No I would not like to find the file size, but view the progress of the single file's zip.

With your code, the `entryStream.Position` always equals to `buffer.Length` and the `ZipArchive` class doesn't include progress reporting. So, what you need to think about is reporting progress for async task in your code by yourself.

Please see the relevant information: [Enabling Progress and Cancellation in Async APIs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/) and the relevant thread [How to do progress reporting using Async/Await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19980112/how-to-do-progress-reporting-using-async-await).

Comment: No I would not like to find the file size, but view the progress of the single file's zip.